# Can I report a cheater in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: steam, dark-souls-3

Yesterday I got invaded by some guy I could not deal any damage to him at all. He didn't even attempt to dodge or block my attacks. I think he could be a cheater.

I understand that due to game mechanics and number of players, it's almost impossible to be invaded by the same player a second time, but I still want him to be punished.

How can I report cheating?

I'm playing on PC from Steam.

Comment: Wiki says the following: "*However, it is also possible to get invaded by a player that is of a lower soul level, but with much better gear (people transfer powerful gear to lower level characters just for this purpose).*" Are you sure the guys was exactly cheating, or could it be explained by something like gear twinking?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I don't have any video of what happened. His gear really looked like some advanced stuff - set from knight with funny metal hat from trailer. But even in case of advanced gear I expect to deal some damage - like 1 or 10, but I did none at all - numbers with damage never appeared. Anyway, I'm in search for report system, where support guys will investigate case and make a decision.

Comment: Here's some advice for Souls 2 from the top of Google. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=438608328

Comment: It will make sense if Steam's Report Violation works for DS3 the same way as for DS2! Thanks, please, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can report a player on Steam.

To do this, open Steam overlay in-game (`Shift+Tab` by default), click "View Players" in the Friends box.

[image: View Players]

This will show you all players you've met in Steam games, ordered by time.
If you have already left the game, same list can be accessed from Steam client menu, **View** -> **Players**.

From the list, find the suspected cheater and navigate to their profile. You can report the player from there.

[image: Report Player]
[image: Report Reason]

Source: [Steamcommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=438608328)

Comment: How is this done in Big Picture mode?

Comment: @seo I couldn't properly test (couldn't enter Big Picture Friends screen with a keyboard/mouse), but I guess it should be somewhere around Friends. If not, however, it is entirely possible that this functionality is missing from Big Picture, so you'd have to switch to windowed.